# Search results home page title not showing properly but other pages do?

Tags: seo, meta

Usually Google search results shows the `<title>` value as the title on the results, but with a CraftCMS website it shows the websites name with a colon and removes the last segment? I've checked on another CraftCMS website and the same thing is happening.

Code: `<title>Book Store | City Name | Something</title>`

Google Results: (Whats happening currently)

> **MyBookCompany: | Book Store | City Name**

Google Results: (What it should be)

> **Book Store | City Name | Something**

All other pages of the website meta title renders properly on their searched page. The DOM shows the code title correctly. Using no plugin and this dates latest CraftCMS version. How do I remove this default behaviour that is happening only on the home page?

Answer (score 1):

Could the Google account holder for the domain have set the listing to use a different value than what's in the title element?

Craft doesn't do anything like this out of the box and the SEO plugins that would change the title value you'd see that in the DOM. Is there a meta tag in the head maybe that Google reads to override the title element?

There's no default front-end templating in Craft CMS so whatever is doing this is most likely either whatever the developer's added to the homepage or layout template or Google itself.